# VPN Vs Hotspot Shield

Tags: vpn

A VPN is a Virtual Network that is used to hide IP address of the attacker.
A Hotspot Shield is also used to change IP address which hides the origin IP.

What is the difference between VPN and Hotspot Shield?

What is more secure to use?

Comment: Hotspot Shield is just a VPN service, so what's your question? https://www.google.com/search?q=Hotspot+Shield&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to elaborate more a VPN is a virtual Network that is used to hide IP address of the attacker.

I wouldn't agree with that. A VPN is not about hiding an IP address. This may be an side-effect, but normally one would use a VPN to (securely) connect to another network from the "outside", e.g. the Internet.

Note, however, that VPN is not referring to a specific product. Its more generically describing a concept.

> A Hotspot sheild is also used to change IP address which hides the original ip.

After some research I think "hotspot shield" is a specific (proprietary) VPN product with the main goal to make your anonymous.

> what is more secure to use.

First of all I don't think it makes any sense to compare a technology as a whole against a specific product. Secondly without you telling us what you mean with "secure" we can't evaluate it for you. Personally I don't like the proprietary nature of "hotspot shield" and I think there are better solutions (one of which is Tor, if all you want is anonymity).

Answer (score -2):

TOR has been shown to no longer be secure.  It was at one time, but since the Edward Snowden revelations, we now know that it has been compromised by the NSA. For that reason, I would never use it in a situation where my life -- or my most sensitive data -- depended upon its' level of security.

The proprietary product "Hotspot Shield" claims to protect both the IP address AND the apps on a phone or internet device, preventing them from surreptitiously accessing the internet without your knowledge or consent, when operating in insecure locations such as a public wifi hotspot.  However, as the company is based in Germany, and as we already know that Germany cooperates fully with the NSA in turning over any user data they have, I am currently looking for a better option.

The same company offers a plain VPN, with no app protection, but the same caveat applies.  Although their apps are free, and they claim that they do not collect user data, we have only their word, and we know that any information they have, they will turn over if requested.

Comment: TOR was never mentioned in the question

Comment: The rest of the answer doesn't really address the question. It's more of a review of the Hotspot Shield product.

Comment: "TOR has been shown to no longer be secure. It was at one time, but since the Edward Snowden revelations, we now know that it has been compromised by the NSA." <- this is utterly, absolutely untrue. In fact, the Tor network was shown, by the NSA revelations, to currently be the most secure anonymity network, and so strong in fact that they have to target Tor users browsers to have any chance at deanonymizing them with any likelyhood.